# MAMP php 5.2 to 5.3.6 causing problems

Tags: php, mamp

I'm using MAMP on OSx Lion. I switched from PHP 5.2.17 to 5.3.6, and now I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class ClassName
```

Everything works in php 5.2. I did a quick grep and this is the only place where I declare this class. Always using require_once so this should rule out multiple inclusions of a script.

Not really sure where to even start looking. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try adding `debug_print_backtrace()` at the top of the file that has the class, to see where the include is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You may have given your class the name that an internal PHP library have if not in your project. Try renaming your class and check.